# Review Etiquette

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette

I've searched and checked out many questions on meta about how to handle reviews. There is mostly helpful information already available. There is still one particular thing I'm not sure about.

If one is reviewing a post and clicks "Skip" I'm assuming that it stays in the review queue? So, if I see that a post has already had some helpful comments from incidental users before it ended up in the queue and needs no input, is it better for me to click "No Action Needed", even though I didn't do anything? In this case, "I'm Done" is not active. I'm assuming that if the system works sensibly, only a post that has been "Skip"ped will stay in the review queue?

I have reviewed posts that were earlier reviewed by someone else: [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/159236). Does this mean this was "Skip"ped and then I came along and clicked "No Action Needed"? I suppose my main concern is about appropriate etiquette. I don't want to claim credit for reviewing a post that has already been reviewed. But, if a post has some incidental comments that already point in the right direction, that I would have posted myself had they not been there, I believe they shouldn't stay in the review queue.

I am assuming that "Skip" is for when I do want someone else to review the post when, for whatever reason, I'm not sure what should be done myself?

Comment: [Seems somewhat related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12633/is-it-rude-to-skip-most-edits).

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes, I agree it's somewhat related but I'm asking about the etiquette and appropriate use of "No Further Action Needed". I could have answered my own question but I preferred having the opinions of others more experienced here before deciding for myself.

Comment: The [MSO review faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/214632) and the [MSO review guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/214632) seem mostly appropriate.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes, but, can I assume categorically then, in the example I have provided in the OP, that if someone else is listed as reviewing this post before me, the only reason I'm seeing it is because they clicked "Skip". And also, that the posts we are reviewing are meanwhile able to be commented and edited by incidental users (incidental meaning not from the review queue).

Comment: @GeoffPointer: I have the feeling that you did not read the links I provided.  Every user has their own "review queue" and items are only removed from all review queues when enough (certainly more than one, unless that user has special powers) users actually review it. Skipping means precisely that: you skip that review, removing it from your own queue, but this action does not appear in any review summary. And, yes, items to be reviewed are still available for users to act on outside of the queue.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Not at all, I went to those links immediately upon reading your first comment. I'm new to this and absorbing and understanding what looks like large amounts information from where I'm standing is not as straightforward as for someone who might already take the large part of it for granted. I'm certainly not ignoring you. Your last comment has expanded on a key point made in the first link you pointed to, which is helpful. So, skipping doesn't appear in the review summary, but other actions do get you a mention. I needed to have this discussion, it helped me. Thankyou.